# Sklearn roc_auc_score value for binary outcome and continuous outcome

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, roc, auc

I am trying to use roc_auc_score from sklearn to evaluate two models. The first one is Random Forest, and the second one is kNN classifier. It's a binary classification problem. But I have a problem since the output types of these two models are different.

For the Random Forest, the output is the probability, some thinking like below.

```
[0.1, 0.4, 0.6, ..., 0.9]
```

For the kNN classifier, the outcome is binary like

```
[0,0,1,...,1]
```

The ground truth is binary values.

I am wondering if I directly use

```
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
roc_auc_score(labels, predictions)
```

Are these roc_auc values from these two models comparable? Since the first one is continuous output the other is discrete? Or should I convert the first one into binary as well? Like element below 0.5 is 0 and above 0.5 is 1?

Answer (score 0):

KNN Classifier has a method `predict_proba` which should return probabilities - see the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html#sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.predict_proba).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot directly use roc_auc_score as it would complain from continuous values. This is meaningful because roc-auc scoring is useful for classification problems. If you would like to handle with such continuous values you must update your predictions in a such way that it should only contain integer values representing labels. One such useful strategy for the binary classification problem is that you can set all predictions (assuming they are between 0 and 1) above 0.5 as 1 and the rest is zero. Because in the end, having a score larger than 0.5 means that your method favors label one to another, vice versa.